# Manga where the main character is isekaied and teleported to a house where he can't leave the yard, and he saves a girl that's being chased

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

He can't leave the yard and he saves a girl that's being chased. And he's practically invincible in the yard.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this question by looking at the check lists in [this thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question), then [edit]ing it to include any further details that come to mind. In particular, it'd be helpful to know whether this was in full colour or mostly black & white. Also, who or what was the girl being chased by?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might be thinking of ***[My House is a Magic Power Spot](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/sx7q5r8/ore-no-ie-ga-maryoku-spot-datta-ken-sundeiru-dake-de-sekai-saikyou)***.

From Baka-Updates:

> Living carefree at home is the greatest shortcut...my house is the world's greatest Magic Power Spot. That being the case, both my house and I were summoned to another world by some guys who were aiming for it. However, I've been living in this place for many years and my body is, apparently, abnormally overflowing with magic. Due to some unforeseen circumstances by those guys who summoned me, they quickly ran away. Be that as it may, there are still some ill-mannered people who covet the magic leaking out of my house. I won't give up my house to those people! I'm going to wield my power as I please!

The protagonist wakes up to discover that he and his house have been transported to the middle of a forest in another world. It turns out that his house is now sitting in a 'magic power spot,' which makes him incredibly powerful within that vicinity. Quite early in the story, he also save a young witch who's being chased by a dragon.

However, I don't think the protagonist is actually confined to that area. He just chooses to stay there because he can conjure up everything he needs on the spot. Plus, he wishes to defend his home from various people who mean to take it from him.

Answer (score 2):

Could this be *[Jobless Reincarnation](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mushoku_Tensei)* (Mushoku Tensei)?

The protagonist suffers from crippling agoraphobia as a result of bullying he suffered in the mundane world.

You can see the anime version below.

Comment: That probably describes hundreds of isekai.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same story. I came back here when I found it. Let me know if this is it.

***[10 nen goshi no HikiNEET o Yamete Gaishutsushitara Jitaku goto Isekai ni Ten'ishiteta](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/33ohvwg/10-nen-goshi-no-hikineet-o-yamete-gaishutsushitara-jitaku-goto-isekai-ni-ten-ishiteta-novel)***.

From Baka-Updates:

> Houjou Yuuji, 30 years old, jobless, hikkomori for 10 years. Using his parents’ death as the impetus, he decides to rid himself of his hikkomori life and leaves the house. What awaited him, however, was a different world that he was not used to, creatures strutting about that he didn’t recognize.
>
> This is the story of a man transported to the another world, as he lives in relative peace with his beloved dog Kotarou – his house, with electricity, water, gas, and the internet somehow still connected.
>
> One day while exploring the forest near his house he finds a girl named Alice, and becomes her guardian. Thus, 4 years after he is transported to this world, Yuuji resolves to venture into his first town.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do note, however, that a [previous answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/264246/122024) was already marked as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by the OP, as denoted by the green tick next to it. This means that the OP believes that answer correctly identified the story they were looking for.

Comment: Still, we encourage good answers that match the question, even if there already is an accepted answer, because it may help someone in the future.